# Control ID of aspx page

Tags: asp.net, controls, updatepanel

Iam not sure if it has one.It might be a stupid question.

But I want to give Triggers like this in my dropdown's Update Panel

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Control ID of Page" EventName="Load">
</Triggers>
```

Note: dropdown is Telerik Radcombox.

Can anyone tell me what to give in the Control ID part?

Comment: So you want DropDown to trigger an update of the UpdatePanel? then just put ID of the drop down there

Comment: I cant put ID of the dropdown..actually i ahve tried that..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would use the Load event; events for triggers are client actions that trigger a server action, such as SelectedIndexChanged of a DropDownList when `AutoPostBack="true"` or Button Click event.  Load happens during the natural postback and doesn't get triggered from the client.  You can't specify the ClientID of the page for that reason.  However, you could just use `UpdateMode="Always"` to always trigger asyncronous, or include more details of the problem.

Comment: Iam trying to populate my telerik dropdown on page load

Iam giving the following code for this:

eg:Radcombobox.SelectedValue=3.But the dd is inside an update panel

Comment: Why does the DD inside the updatepanel matter?  When a full postback occurs, you can change the selected value as necessary; however, if you are updating the value from another value, set UpdateMode="Always" on the panel, and ignore the triggers.  This will get you the result you are looking for.

Comment: Yes I have given UpdateMode="Always".  But for some reason Telerik Radcombobox doesnot get preselected with the value I want.Can you think of any reason for this??